# How can i get callback of just once and always when i select my own launcher App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-ndk

I am making my launcher app.when I select my app as launcher a popup comes for selection and it has two option just once and always when a user clicks just once I want to show a popup and when a user clicks on always I want to show another popup. I am not getting callback of both clicks. How can I do these things. Please suggest me if there is another way?

Comment: use sharedPreference, store one boolean flag there, initially make it false and after you click first popup then make it true.. afterward just check that flag , if false open first popup otherwise another

Comment: but how can I recognize that which popup should be open, because i am not getting callback of 'just Once' and 'always'.

Comment: just make flags and initiliase false initially

Comment: if you choose justonce remain flag as false otherwise make it true

Comment: when you are calling this popup just check flag is true or not.. if false then open otherwise dont open popup

Comment: But the main problem is that I am not getting the callback of click on justonce and always. That is the launcher popup.

Comment: can you put your code ??

Comment: startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME),1000); by this i am launching my app and selection popup comes. That popup gives me two option 1)just once 2)Always i want to detect both option callback