# how to get value from just once or always in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, launcher

I am developing launcher app.when I select my app as launcher a popup comes for selection and it has two option just once and always . I want to get whether the user choose just once or always . I am not getting callback of both clicks.

```
   PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mContext, FakeLauncherActivity.class);
    ComponentName componentName2 = new ComponentName(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName2, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(selector);

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I had refer some same method with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276779/how-can-i-get-callback-of-just-once-and-always-when-i-select-my-own-launcher-app. solution didnt get .

Comment: i found the solution by myself    PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();   PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mContext, FakeLauncherActivity.class);
        ComponentName componentName2 = new ComponentName(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName2, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED.